# Validate pub_sub schema when creating terraform cloud scheduler job

Tags: google-cloud-pubsub, cicd, terraform-provider-gcp

Is there a terraform method to validate pubsub message schemas when setting up jobs to publish said messages?

Terraform for the pubsub topic is set up with a particular schema:

```
message ProtocolBuffer {
 optional string field1 = 1; 
 optional string field2 = 2; 
 required bool field3 = 3;
}
```

Creating a cloud scheduler job using terraform, the message is declared via the "data" variable. Is there any way to validate that the message in this field fits this schema?

```
variable "data" {
  type        = string
  description = "The message payload for PubsubMessage. Pubsub message must contain either non-empty data, or at least one attribute. A base64-encoded string."
  default     = "{\"field3\":\"True\"}"
}
```

e.g. Ideally I'd like another cicd job that validated this message and returned true. Can it be done in terraform or do I have to use the client libraries for pubsub?

Answer (score 0):

The following is what I came up with.

- Create a new CICD step

```
gcloud-validate-schema-dev:
  image: google/cloud-sdk
  script: 
  - - echo $GCP_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_KEY > gcloud-service-key.json
    - gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file gcloud-service-key.json && rm
      gcloud-service-key.json
  - MESSAGE=$(grep 'default     = \"{' <path to file>/variables.tf| cut -b 18-40 |tr -d '\\')
  -  - gcloud beta pubsub schemas validate-message --message-encoding=JSON 
       --schema-name=<SCHEMA NAME> 
       --message=$MESSAGE
```